# How to prevent Jquery Mobile datebox from closing if user selects invalid date

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using jQuery Mobile [datebox plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) to select the date range. If user selects the start date greater than end date, then i want to show the alert and keep the datebox open.

```
  $('#sDate').on('datebox', function (event, payload) {
                if (payload.method === 'set') {
                    if (payload.date > eDate) {
                        window.alert('Select start date less than end date.');
            //Keep datebox open
                    }
                    else {
                     //Proceed with data filtering
                    }
                }
            });
```

But Datebox is getting closed. Is there any option of datebox which allows to prevent datebox from closing (probably without any hack or work around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yDyqs/2/)**

Just add e.stopImmediatePropagation(); after the alert:

```
$('#sDate').on('datebox', function (event, payload) {
    if (payload.method === 'set') {
        if (payload.date > eDate) {
            window.alert('Select start date less than end date.');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fiddle demo, it is working as expected. In my case instead of windows alert, I am using the Alertify jquery plugin library to show the alerts using AngularJS framework. Some how it is still not stopping/preventing the datebox from closing. I tried even replacing the 'Alertify' with windows alert as well.

Comment: i updated my fiddle to use alertify and it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yDyqs/3/  So something else is going on. Can you make a fiddle that reproduces the issue?